# Android: Have TextView width match ImageView in horizontal recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recycler view which contains an Image and below that a title. I need for the recyclerview to display all the images with the same separation and below the text. If the text exceeds the width of the image it should either wrap or be cut off. However, with my current setup long texts are causing huge gaps between the images because they remain in a single line.

This is the xml for the recycler view item:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/media_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/topimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/topImage"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Also, within the recycler view adapter I'm setting the width/height of the image to a 5:7 aspect ratio like this:

```
    double widthDouble = (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2) * 0.9;
    int width = (int) widthDouble;
    int height = (int) (width * 0.7);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    viewHolder.topImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
    viewHolder.topImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

How can I change this in order to have recycler view item be the width of the Image and have the text wrap under the image?

PS: I'm using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your TetxView multi-line using

```
android: singleline = "false"
```

and then use the "max lines" property to set the max lines permitted.

Comment: Thanks but even with this addition, the recyclerView item is the width of the full text instead of the width of the image. I need it to be the width of the image and have the text wrap if needed.

Comment: I can see what you are using a Relative Layout. You can make your life easier using a Constraint Layout. If I were you, in the TextView, try to use the: 'layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="yourImageViewIdHere" and 'layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="yourImageViewIdHere". (After changing to a Constraint Layout) You can check how to use it here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout